# Liberty Null pointer exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, java-ee-8

I used open-liberty 19.0.0.6 .but this application server do not working with ssl port (https) on docker container .

receive this nullPointerException :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.h2internal.hpack.H2HeaderTable.getHeaderEntry(H2HeaderTable.java:41)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.h2internal.hpack.H2Headers.encodeHeader(H2Headers.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.h2internal.hpack.H2Headers.encodeHeader(H2Headers.java:320)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.HttpRequestMessageImpl.pushNewRequest(HttpRequestMessageImpl.java:2066)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpRequestImpl.pushNewRequest(HttpRequestImpl.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer40.srt.http.HttpPushBuilder.push(HttpPushBuilder.java:289)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.pushResource(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:434)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.encodeResourceURL(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:381)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.encodeResourceURL(ExternalContextWrapper.java:110)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlStylesheetRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlStylesheetRenderer.java:232)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:675)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:555)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:597)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:527)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1897)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:315)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1255)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:743)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:182)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.JaspiServletFilter.doFilter(JaspiServletFilter.java:56)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:996)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1134)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4975)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1061)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:417)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:466)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:331)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:302)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.h2internal.H2StreamProcessor$Http2Ready.run(H2StreamProcessor.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

and this is my server.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <library id="MySQLLib">
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/mysql" includes="*.jar" />
    </library>
    <dataSource jndiName="JTA-Connection" transactional="true">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySQLLib" />
        <properties databaseName="${database.name}"
                    serverName="${database.hostname}"
                    portNumber="${database.port}"
                    user="${database.username}"
                    password="${database.password}" />
    </dataSource>
    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm" />
    <httpSession securityIntegrationEnabled="false" />
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  httpPort="8080"
                  httpsPort="9443"
                  host="0.0.0.0"
                  protocolVersion="http/2">
        <httpOptions http2="enabled" />
    </httpEndpoint>
    <webContainer disableXPoweredBy="true" />
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true" />
    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
    <logging consoleLogLevel="ERROR" />
</server>
```

and this is my bootstrap.properties file :

```
### Server Configuration ###
default.http.port=8080
default.https.port=9443
default.hostname=localhost

### Database Configuration ###
database.name=logmug
database.hostname=mysql.docker.io
database.port=3306
database.username=root
database.password=rootpass
```

**Note :** my application working on http (port 80) connection without any problem , only https(port 443) has this problem .
**Note :** this problem resolved only on docker container , i test my application on local machin (outside container) all ports work without any problem .

**This is application server null pointer exception**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519980/http-2-support-on-open-liberty does this ring any bells?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, this NPE occurs because an HTTP header without any value set is passed into a PushBuilder.  Given the stack it looks like the bad header originates in Open Liberty's Servlet 4 implementation. I've opened an issue to track this - can you add your feedback? https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/8474

As for why your application is working locally, I'd check to verify that HTTP/2 is actually in use.  If you're on Java 8, a specific environment is required to get HTTP/2 working over SSL via ALPN - see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_alpnsupport.html